Use AWS CodePipeline to build a Docker image to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk?
We currently use AWS CodePipeline/CodeBuild to build our Typescript application and then deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. The process is currently:
CodePipeline:

Source - Fetch code from GitHub
Build - Install NPM packages and build/transpile code
Deploy - Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using the EB action provider
Migrate - Again install NPM packages and build code + execute our database migration scripts

Elastic Beanstalk:
During the Deploy step, I think that EB again builds the code because it creates a new Docker image (based on the app's Dockerfile), and then deploys that image.
I'm also under the impression that every time EB scales-out, it again rebuilds the Docker image during the deployment process.
This is all very slow, and I'd love to change it to this:

Source - Fetch code from GitHub
Build - Build by creating a Docker image
Deploy - Deploy the image to Elastic Beanstalk
Migrate - Start the Docker image + execute our database migration scripts

Elastic Beanstalk:
Simply start the already built Docker image when deploying or scaling-out.
Is this scenario possible? Can anyone provide me with tips/references on how to achieve this?
